# Spring Security >5.0.0 removed Md5PasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring project using Spring security. I was using Spring Boot 1.5 and now I migrated to Spring Boot 2.0.

I noticed that [Md5PasswordEncoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.M5/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/Md5PasswordEncoder.html) has been removed in the final release of Spring Security. Instead `Md4PasswordEncoder` is still present even if deprecated (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/api/).

Should I use extenal MD5 encoder or is the classed moved somewhere else?

Comment: You shouldn't really use `MD5` at all.

Answer (score 13):

The fact that `Md5PasswordEncoder` ceased to exist doesn't mean that Spring Security 5 isn't able to create `MD5` hashes. It uses `new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("MD5")` for that.

There are two options, both work with the new `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`, which expects a password prefix to determine the hashing algorithm, for example `{MD5}password_hash`:

*Either* set the default password encoder to `MD5` (in uppercase!), so if passwords aren't prefixed, then the default encoder is applied:

```
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
passwordEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("MD5"));
```

*Or* prefix the existing password hashes in the database with `{MD5}`. This way the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` delegates to the `MD5' hasher. Something like:

```
update myusertable set pwd = '{MD5}' || pwd;
```

Comment: Can you specify which package to include for PasswordEncoderFactories?

Comment: that should be `org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories` from `spring-security-core`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use MD5 you can customize :

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new PasswordEncoder() {
        @Override
        public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
            return getMd5(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
            return getMd5(charSequence.toString()).equals(s);
        }
    };
}

public static String getMd5(String input) {
    try {
        // Static getInstance method is called with hashing SHA
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        // digest() method called
        // to calculate message digest of an input
        // and return array of byte
        byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(input.getBytes());

        // Convert byte array into signum representation
        BigInteger no = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);

        // Convert message digest into hex value
        String hashtext = no.toString(16);

        while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
            hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
        }

        return hashtext;
    }

    // For specifying wrong message digest algorithms
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown"
                + " for incorrect algorithm: " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still return null exp for the id

Answer (score 6):

You should use `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder` instead. [Here](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2018/01/13/spring-security-5-new-password-storage-format/) is a good article about switching to the new interface.

Comment: I found this article a little bit more intuitive https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-password-storage

Answer (score 2):

Spring remove MD5 because it is not secure enough anymore. You should use Bcrypt.

Comment: I need to use MD5 because a payment gateway requires to hash some part of the request with MD5. It's not my choice ;-) I'm using Bcrypt for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

My solution as below:

```
protected static String mergePasswordAndSalt(String password, Object salt, boolean strict) {
        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }

        if ((strict) && (salt != null) && ((salt.toString().lastIndexOf("{") != -1) || (salt.toString().lastIndexOf("}") != -1))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot use { or } in salt.toString()");
        }

        if ((salt == null) || ("".equals(salt))) {
            return password;
        }
        return password + "{" + salt.toString() + "}";
    }

    public static String EncodingPassword(String password, String salt) {
        String merge = mergePasswordAndSalt(password,salt,false);
        return DigestUtils.md5Hex(merge);
    }
```

use the function above to replace the code below:

```
new  Md5PasswordEncoder().encodePassword(String rawPass, Object salt);
```

From the source code of Md5PasswordEncoder in spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar, we can find out how it handle the password and salt:

```
  //org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.BasePasswordEncoder.class

  protected String mergePasswordAndSalt(String password, Object salt, boolean strict)
  {
    if (password == null) {
      password = "";
    }

    if ((strict) && (salt != null) && (
      (salt.toString().lastIndexOf("{") != -1) || (salt.toString().lastIndexOf("}") != -1))) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot use { or } in salt.toString()");
    }

    if ((salt == null) || ("".equals(salt))) {
      return password;
    }
    return password + "{" + salt.toString() + "}";
  }
```